# Modifying the polar coordinates of a disk with random dots in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a dynamic random dots stereogram by updating the position of the dots, so that I can get an inward motion of the dots (optic flow).
I first created a disk filled with dots whose position is randomised:

```
se = strel('disk',4);
x = linspace(-1,1,768); %generates 768 points in a vector with a [-1:1] interval
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,x); %generates a rectangular grid in replicating the x vector.
[T,R] = cart2pol(X,Y); 

threshold = 1 - (dot_nb / 768^2); %dot_nb=5;
Rd = double(rand(768,768)>threshold);
Rd(R>0.95 | R<0.06)=0; %remove some of the dots in order to get a circle and no dots in the middle of it
```

I am now trying to update the location of the dots at a specific refresh rate (20Hz) but I am having troubles with it.
I thought the following lines of code (which are in a bigger loop controlling the frame rate) could work but obviously something is missing and I do not know how else I could do it:

```
update = 0.1; 
for i = 1:size(R,1) %R is the matrix with the radius values of the dots
for j = 1:size(R,2)
 if R(i,j)<0.95 && R(i,j)>0.06
     R(i,j) = R(i,j)-update;
 else
     R(i,j)=0;
 end
end
end
```

Has anyone any idea how I could do to get what I'm looking for?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: The code you've provided seems to do what it says it's will - however with the parameters specified, `R` will be matrix of zeros in no more than 9 frames, or at 20 Hz less than half a second. What is it doing when you try and how does that differ from what you expect it to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, after a small number of frames, I will have only zeros. I am still working on how to make those dots reborn. But my main problem is that I am unable to display the image of the dots with the modification of the R values. When I write "imshow(Rd)" a couple of times to get the different frames, it does not take the R values into account at all. And I cannot write "imshow(Rd(R))" so I do not know how to get my images to build an optic flow video.

Comment: `imshow` doesn't really display dots - it displays squares on a Cartesian grid. The coordinates you define for the squares in your 768-by-768 grid happen to define dots that are aligned as a grid initially, but by calling `imshow(Rd)` you're not supplying any information about those coordinates - the squares are just lined up in the same order so you get the same effect. When you change those coordinates the dots no longer necessarily form a grid, so this doesn't work...

Comment: You either need to use `plot` to position each point according to its coordinates, or convert the polar coordinates back to Cartesian coordinates so you can turn squares in your original 768-by-768 image on or off depending on whether their original coordinates are the nearest ones to the new coordinate of each dot.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!